The given key 'blazorpack' was not present in the dictionary
This error showed after connecting to Azure SignalR. But when using signal r service everything works fine.
No console error showing and signalR is connected.
services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents()
.AddCircuitOptions(c => c.DetailedErrors = true)
.AddHubOptions(h => h.EnableDetailedErrors=true);

if (!UserAzureSignalR)
{
    services.AddSignalR(options => { options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; });
}
else
{
    services.AddSignalR(options => { options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; })
        .AddAzureSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = AppConfig.SignalRConnectionString;
            options.ServerStickyMode = Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServerStickyMode.Required;
        });
}



Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost: Error: Unhandled exception in circuit 'ugiugh987689769889khghjghjg'.

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'blazorpack' was not present in the dictionary.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.get_Item(TKey key) at Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.DefaultHubMessageSerializer.SerializeMessage(String protocol, HubMessage message) at Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceLifetimeManagerBase1.SerializeProtocol(String protocol, String method, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceLifetimeManager1.CreateMessage(String connectionId, String methodName, Object[] args, ClientConnectionContext serviceConnectionContext) at Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceLifetimeManager1.SendConnectionAsync(String connectionId, String methodName, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer.CaptureAsyncExceptions(Task task)

Could you please tell me what's the blazor version for this case? Could you please share the whole program.cs codes for this blazor app? Besides, when this error shows just once when the application running or keep showing this error?

@BrandoZhang I updated the question, This is blazor 8 on mvc core .net 8. it shows on initial load, data are loaded but reactivity are not working like OnClick()
